# recall and precision in rapidminer

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer, precision-recall

there is a dataset in excel containing some labels in column A(I call it cluster label) and some attributes in column B(I call them cluster component). These data show the best clustering result.

But I don't know how to compute recall and precision of other clustering method using these data in rapidminer!

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

The following [link](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/counting-clusters-part-iv.html) gives an example of using the RapidMiner operator "Map Clustering on Labels". This maps known cluster labels to the cluster allocated by the clustering algorithm. From this, the output can be used to create a confusion matrix where precision and recall can be determined.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you have more number of classes/labels the precision and recall has to be for individual classes.